# SQL Joining multiple tables without returning the same joined id twice

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 (MYSQL) tables, A, B, and C.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN c on c.a_id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

I have 4 entries on the B table with B.a_id = 1:

```
B.id | b.a_id
1    | 1
2    | 1
3    | 1
4    | 1
```

I also have 2 such entries on the C table

```
C.id | C.a_id
10   | 1
11   | 1
```

The return gives 8 results:

```
C.id | B.id
10    | 1
10    | 2
10    | 3
10    | 4
11    | 1
11    | 2
11    | 3
11    | 4
```

Is there a way to get the results to not repeat the same C and B objects, and return something more like this?

```
C.id | B.id
10    | 1
11    | 2
NULL  | 3
NULL  | 4
```

In other words, I want to say "give me everything that maps to A=1, but do not repeat the same C or B's twice".  In my actual data, I'm joining closer to 10 tables, and with all the permutations of all the joined tables, the results are often thousands of rows long.

There is a similar question here [Connecting Multiple Tables in SQL while Limiting Exponential Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704898/connecting-multiple-tables-in-sql-while-limiting-exponential-results) , but I want to avoid inner selects to the extent possible.  I feel this is a common enough use of a database that there should be

Comment: Does DISTINCT work for you?

Comment: In your ideal return values, are you just arbitrarily putting C=10 and B=1 on the same row?  why?  Perhaps C=NULL and B=1,2,3,4 and B=NULL and C=1,2 would make more sense?

Comment: I'm familiar with the keyword, but I'm not sure how to use it in context here in a way that helps.  if I just do SELECT DISTINCT(*), that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @mikey - A solution that would only add the number results rather than multiply them would be good enough too.

That said, the ideal result would be more compressed if possible, and the matching of C.id and B.id can be arbitrary, as long as allthe data is there somewhere (i.e. if C=10 matches to B=3 and C=11 matches to B=4, while B's 1 and 2 have C=NULL, that would be perfectly acceptable).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is *not* simple SQL, and you should not expect it to be easy in relational databases.

I would advise you to put all the values in a single column, with another column specifying where they came from.  This results in a large `union all` type of query:

```
select 'b' as which, b.id
from a join b on b.a_id = a.id and a.id = 1
union all
select 'c', c.id
from a join c on c_aid = b.id and a.id = 1
. . .
```

The results are not exactly what you want.

If you really want the data in separate columns, then you need to use a trick to assign a row number to each row.  You can then aggregate the result by the row number.  Something like this:

```
select rn,
       MAX(case when which = 'b' then id end) as b,
       MAX(case when which = 'b' then id end) as c
from (select 'b' as which, b.id, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
      from a join b on b.a_id = a.id and a.id = 1 cross join (select @rn := 0) const
      union all
      select 'c', c.id, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
      from a join c on c_aid = b.id and a.id = 1 cross join (select @rn := 0) const
     ) t
group by rn
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a fundamental of using SQL to retrieve data; it retrieves data in complete rows, each with the same columns, as defined in the projection requested in the `SELECT` clause. Any time I run into issues like this with SQL, what has helped me is to ask myself three questions:

1. What would the result rows I want look like? I.e., what columns would they have?
2. How will the database know how to fill each column?
3. How will the database know which rows to return?

Answering these questions for any given scenario has helped me to step back and see why a certain `JOIN` or `GROUP BY` was causing me trouble; generally, it's due to asking the database for something that it just doesn't have any concept of.

In your case, retrieving rows of data, there is no way for the database to give you multiple rows from table B and multiple rows from table C *without* giving you the Cartesian product of those rows. If you don't want the duplicate data, you'll have to issue the `SELECT`s separately.

Phrased in answer to the questions above: Each row would have all the data from table A, and... uhm... what? There's no way to fit multiple rows from tables B and C into an arbitrary number of columns, so that won't work. There's no way to return short rows of data from B and C because every row is the same length. It'll have to return a full row for each row in B and each row in C, which gives you exactly the scenario you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Some one might use it, but seems easy....

could you try the following...

Instead of Left Joint

```
SELECT * FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN c on c.a_id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

Use the Following Inner Join

```
SELECT * FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
INNER JOIN c on c.a_id = a.id
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

That should work...I think..